If the righteous are not spiritually alive in heaven then from where did the spirits of Moses and Elijah come from at the transfiguration?
According to the author of this article who is from White Throne Ministries, he teaches that the spirits of the dead are not in heaven but sleep in the sands awaiting one of the two resurrections. He quotes the following verse which was written by Peter under the influence of The Holy Spirit.
Acts 2:29

"2:29 Men and brethren, let me freely speak unto you of the patriarch David, that he is both dead and buried, and his sepulchre is with us unto this day.

Acts 2:34

For David is not ascended into the heavens:"

Jesus talked of a separation of believers and non-believers at death through the parable of the rich man and Lazarus and reinforced that teaching on the cross when He told him that he will be with him in paradise that same Friday.
Luke 23:43

Jesus said to him, “I tell you the truth, today you will be with me in paradise

He then says that a different meaning would be conveyed if that comma were to be removed and also that from other events that happened on that Friday we learn that Jesus did not go to paradise on that Friday because of the words Jesus said to Mary after rising from the dead.
John 20:17

Jesus saith to her, Touch me not: for I have not yet ascended to my Father:

According to that author, the words above prove that Jesus did not go to paradise on that Friday, hence justifying the need for a comma in the promise to thief verse. He backs it all up with all the verses from Acts that none of the Fathers have ascended to heaven but my question is, The Book of Revelation says there are martyrs under the altar who cry out to God for revenge against the inhabitants of the earth. These are the spirits of those martyrs that are spiritually in heaven.
Revelation 6:10

the souls of martyrs who were killed for their faith in God cry out from under the altar, asking God when he will judge and avenge their deaths:

The verse above is the first proof that the saints spiritually unite with God in paradise but their flesh await a re-union in the resurrection.
The second proof is the presence of Elijah and Moses during the transfiguration for we know Moses died and the angels buried him, Elijah went to heaven with a chariot of fire. Where did their spirits come from during the transfiguration if the spirits of the righteous do not inherit paradise after death?

From their official web site, White Throne Ministries are based in Ghana, West Africa. They believe Christ Jesus began the first phase of the judgment in the most holy place of the heavenly sanctuary in 1844. Why should we pay attention to their views?

@NigelJ, because they are try to reason logically but their reasoning is fallacy to the souls of the martyrs slain because of the word of God and the spirits of Elijah and Moses that were present during the transfiguration

@NigelJ, we discussed this earlier on and I agree with your interpretation of the rich man and Lazarus is a true record of what happened and that those figures Rich man and Lazarus lived on the earth oblivious to men but not to God, same as the story of the good Samaritan, after we die, we get an immediate confirmation of our eternal destinies

I answered a similar question on the Hermeneutics.SE site:

No, Moses and Elijah weren't resurrected so that Peter, James, and
John could see them.  We already know this because John
3:13 tells us
that "no man hath ascended up to heaven".
Look at how Matthew describes the event:

And, behold, there appeared unto them Moses and Elias talking with him.
— Matthew 17:3
…
And as they came down from the mountain, Jesus charged them, saying, Tell the vision to no man, until the Son of man be risen again from
the dead.
— Matthew 17:9

Notice that they "appeared unto them", and that later Jesus refers to
it as a "vision".
Visions appear throughout the Bible.  They are not physical things,
but something that happens in the minds of those experiencing them.
In Acts 10, Peter later had a vision of unclean animals being
presented as food:

… he fell into a trance and saw … . Peter doubted in himself what this vision which he had seen should mean ….

Similarly, in the book of Revelation, John describes his vision of the
Day of the Lord as being seen "in the spirit".
Visions are just that.  They aren't real physical events.
…
— Did God resurrect Moses? - Biblical Hermeneutics Stack Exchange

And a related one here:

Notice how the transfiguration is described a few verses later:

And as they came down from the mountain, Jesus charged them, saying,
Tell the vision to no man, until the Son of man be risen again from
the dead.

This was not an actual appearance by Elijah and Moses, who were dead,
buried, and unconscious.  It was a "vision".  The same Greek word
"ὅραμα" (horama) was used elsewhere (e.g. Peter's vision of the
unclean animals) to describe similar dream-like situations, not
actual events.
When one dreams or experiences a vision, one doesn't need to be
explicitly told who people are, one simply knows.
— How did Peter recognize Elijah and Moses?


what about Elijah, we have proof he didn't die, from where did his soul come from because he didn't taste death

yeah, even the visions of the son of man or a sign appearing in heaven are creatd in the minds of the prophets?

@SoFewAgainstSoMany, the "..." at end of the first quotation talks about Elijah. Also see my answers to a list of personages, which are Biblically stated to be in heaven? and How did Elijah ascend to heaven? - Hermeneutics.SE.

Would Jesus talk to people whose spirits are still in the grave unless he summoned them? Jesus is Holy and he would not create something in the minds of the disciples that are untrue

@SoFewAgainstSoMany, the scripture doesn't say, but it could easily have been a "true" vision of what it will be like in the Kingdom of God after the saints have been resurrected.

you havent addressed the souls of the martyrs below the altar, what about that and they speak out against the inhabitants of the earth?

@SoFewAgainstSoMany, almost the entire book of Revelation is a vision. The metaphor of the dead speaking to the living is common even in non-religious works. See my answer to In the Book of Revelation, does soul (psyché) describe the immaterial portion of human beings that survive death? — Hermeneutics.SE, which gives a modern non-religious use of this device, John McCrae's "In Flanders Fields" poem.

Sure, so Elijah didnt go to heaven with the chariot of fire?

@SoFewAgainstSoMany, "heaven" has three different meanings. Given that he was in a whirlwind, it's obvious that the heaven in this case simply meant up into the atmosphere. My first reference lists several occasions when the mortal human Elijah was seen after being taken away.

I will check your answer out

How do you know the spirits of Moses and Elijah were not actually there as witnesses to the transfiguration of Jesus, the fact that the raiment of Jesus was ten times brighter than that of the sun is starting to give me reason to believe The Lord Jesus Christ is God Almighty incarnate

The souls under the altar are all souls following the advent of Christ. Note how the "angel" in Rev. 22:8-9 claims to be "of thy brethren the prophets, and of them which keep the sayings of this book [...]" After Christ's death, before he ascended to heaven, he "descended first into the lower parts of the earth" (Eph. 4:9) where "he went and preached unto the spirits in prison" (1 Pet. 3:18-20).
Without getting too much into the explanations of paradise versus the New Jerusalem and similar arguments, suffice it to say, at the time of the Revelation vision, there is already evidence post ascension of Christ that those dead in Christ are already in their glorified spiritual bodies of the resurrection, appearing like the angels (1 Cor. 15:40-44; Matt. 22:30).
As for Moses and Elijah, Jewish folklore allegedly held that Moses was not actually buried, but that he, too, like Elijah, ascended to God. The speculation of the folklore was that the end of Deuteronomy stating that Moses was buried was written as such to prevent the Jews from worshipping Moses. Although the work, The Assumption of Moses, is incomplete, scholars speculate that the dispute over Moses' body mentioned in Jude 1:9 refers to the folklore supposedly mentioned in this work, and Moses' ascension to heaven.
The Transfiguration, in fact, might actually be gospel evidence that Moses, like Elijah, was taken up to heaven rather than buried, consistent with the speculated folklore. The dead all slept until Christ's death and resurrection. This would include Moses, unless he never died. For those who are inclined to disbelieve the Bible generally, this may also be evidence of the folklore itself being represented in the gospels.
It is also worth noting that both Moses and Elijah had what essentially amounted to glorified spiritual bodies like the angels, which means that both are already in heaven, or from heaven, or however it is one chooses to understand it.

well answered, if Elijah went to heaven, how did he write his letter?

NLT renders Ephesians 4:9 as "Notice that it says “he ascended.” This clearly means that Christ also descended to our lowly world.", meaning that he had come down to Earth from Heaven. Why do you claim this means "After Christ's death, before he ascended to heaven"?
¶ 1 Peter 3:18–20 talks about Christ's talking to the imprisoned spirits and mentions the days of Noah. Again what makes you believe that this was between his death and ascension?
¶ And why do you believe these two scriptures are related?


The NLT is strictly interpretive. It is not a literal translation. It was a paraphrased adaptation a man made for his children. 2) Ephesians specifically says that Christ descended “into the lower parts of the earth.” It doesn’t mean he descended from heaven to earth, but that he descended into the depths of the earth, where Sheol would be. 3) Imprisoned spirits, by context, are those who are asleep. The dead. If Christ descended into hell (Sheol), the dead who are imprisoned there awaiting redemption are clearly those whom he preached to.


@So Few Against So Many, do you mean Enoch? Or are you referring to a document allegedly written by Elijah I’m not aware of? If you mean Enoch, the work is apocryphal. There’s no evidence it was written by Enoch.
